# Comparing Date/time on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Currently on my oracle table, I have the following if condition on my procedure

```
if TO_CHAR(updatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') != '01-JAN-1900 00:00:01' then
```

Suppose the value updatetime from oracle table is **"01-JAN-1900 12:00:01 AM"** , will my if condition be true or false ?

The reason I'm asking is because I am unsure about the format TO_CHAR converts to. Value on the table is in a 12-Hr clock format, while the condition compares with a 24-hr format.

This is my first week working with oracle sql..

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What @Tony Andrews said, but you probably want to make your to_char convert to 24 hour clock if you're comparing it to a string containing 24 hour clock value. Change HH to HH24 like this:

```
if TO_CHAR(updatetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') != '01-JAN-1900 00:00:01' then
```

Comment: What difference will this make, since tony mentioned about the 7 numeric values ? As I'm new to oracle procedures, can u explain how does the variable updatetime obtain its value ? Does it query directly from the DB (hence the 7 numeric values), or does it take the value from the table view ? Hope I made any sense..

Comment: updatetime is held as @Tony says. But you're not comparing your string to updatetime, you're comparing it to the string that is the result of casting updatetime to your defined format. So your defined format needs to match the format of the string you're comparing to..

Comment: @Kyle, in general you'd normally want to do the conversion the other way so that you're comparing using the data type of the column in the database. i.e. `if updatetime != to_date('01-Jan-1900 00:00:01', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') then` - so somparing two DATEs, rather than to VARCHARs. Otherwise you're applying the conversion on every row, which would do more work than needed and wouldn't allow use any (normal) index on the column. In this example you might not care, but something to bear in mind for the future perhaps.

Comment: @Alex Poole : Thanks for the advice.  Unfortunately, after applying the format StevieG mentioned, the if condition is still executing even when the updatetime is set to 01-JAN-1900 00:00:01.  :(

Comment: Strange.. try printing out the result of the to_char to confirm its definitely matching your comparison string..

Answer (score 3):

Oracle DATE columns do not hold the date as a formatted string, it is held (internally) as 7 numeric values: century, year, month, day, hour, minute, second.  So it doesn't matter what format you use in your TO_CHAR.